# Dynamic variables name access?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a ASP.NET.

I added table.

I assigned IDs to columns and lows, such as m1_1, m1_2, ..., m10_10 in HTML.

```
<td id="m1_1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; height: 30px;">&nbsp;</td>
```

and I want to access the IDs as variable in cs.

m1_1.Controls.Add()
m1_2.Controls.Add()
.
.
.
m10_10.Controls.Add()

How can I write it with for loop?

Comment: instead of having 10 names for 10 things, why not just use a single collection at put all your elements there. Then it´s easy to do `m[1][2].Controls.Add(...)`.

Comment: <td id="m1_1"    How to set IDs as m[0]...m[10] in HTML?

Comment: a combination of string.Substring, string.Split and integer.Parse should get you what you need to index the array(s).

Comment: Here, detailed problem is how to convert string to variable name.

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/access-variable-by-string-name.42487/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not looking to use variable names, but in fact controls on the page - that is somewhat different question. You can do this:

```
<td id="m1_1" style="border: 1px solid #000000; height: 30px;" runat="server">&nbsp;</td>
```

And then:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    string strMyControl = "m" + i + "_" + i;
    HtmlTableCell Mytd = Page.FindControl(strMyControl);
    Mytd.InnerText = "bla bla bla";
}
```

So you can have a string name in a variable, and "get/find" that control on the page based on this string - and once you have the control reference, then you can modify and do what you want to that control.